# Slow download and fast upload on usb wi fi card only on desktop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, usb

I have great problem, I am trying to locate problem with my desktop PC, and tried 3 different USB Wi-Fi cards all giving me the same result:

Ping
16 ms,
Download
3.01 Mbps should be around 140 Mbps,
Upload
85.57 Mbps and this one is as it should.

Also tried on other devices and it works wine, I formatted my HDD and reinstalled OS on clean windows 10 same situation, and I am unable to check it on cable.

Does anyone had similar situation?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PC, or something near it, may be generating RF noise that is desensitizing the receiver.

Things to try:

- Put your USB Wi-Fi adapter at the end of a 2 meter USB extender cable to get it away from your PC or other nearby electronics (monitor, printer, whatever).
- Change the channel on your network to a channel far from what it was on. For example, if it's on channel 1, swich to channel 13.
- Switch to 5 GHz instead of 2.4GHz (or vice-versa).